# How does browser knows that the status of the an HTTP call changed?

Tags: javascript, ajax

There are a lot of articles about `AJAX` but not many on how `AJAX` actually makes an `HTTP` request and subsequent calling of suceess/error callbacks.

I have few question about `AJAX`:

1. How does browser knows when `XMLHttpRequest.readyState` changed?
2. How does knower knows how much content has been downloaded/uploaded?
3. How do web apis decide when to push `AJAX` success callback into the event queue? Do the browser trigger some event when `AJAX` is finished?
4. How does the `HTTP` `POST` call initiate from `form` submission differs from the one which is initiated via `AJAX`. (In my understanding, they are same but I would like to confirm it).

Comment: 1. browser manages the whole thing. 2. the content-length header sent by the server, plus a count of arrived data bytes. 3. when it's done with a 2xx header. yes, onreadystatechange and onload. 4. it doesn't vary.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for your comment. I am looking for more clarity and under the hood workings of AJAX and browser. Could you please see my comment on Willem's answer. His answer is pretty much like yours.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` is a browser interface which can be used to do `HTTP` request. The actual implementation of this is in the code of the browser itself (usually `C++`). The term interface is important here, with Javascript you can **interface** with this functionality in an async manner. How it works under the hood is for JS programming not interesting and abstracted away from you.

1. All the browsers API's have there own interal implementation, the browser manages this
2. The browser can checkout the amount of bytes/ Content-Length header send by the server.
3. The native browser implementation (untouchable by JS) pushes the callback into the event queue once the `AJAX` call is succesful.
4. They are both `HTTP` request so in that manner they are the same (given that they use teh same method). However, the form `HTTP` does trigger a page refresh and the `AJAX` call won't refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am looking for more in depth answer. 1. Browser alone can't do that. See [this](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate). Every `XMLHttpRequest.readyState` number mean something which browser can't know unless server tells it (except 0,1).  2. This makes sense. Does headers get sent by server during every TCP cycle?. 3. I am expecting more details answers than "native browser implementation". The same question can be asked for setTimeout and setInterval as well. 4. Makes sense.